# How to show marker location in map when mouse over to a div item - like AirBnb

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, leaflet

I have a page in left side div items like item's image,title,its details, address ex. And on the right side I have a map (Leaflet Map) showing markers of address which taking from all of these left side items. Now I want to display marker location on map when mouse hover to the left information with its address. Shortly you can see live example in [airbnb.com](https://airbnb.com)

I am using React Leaflet for map and React as you see. But data doesn't fetch from db yet, it is dummy data. Address is defined with lat and lng coords

[image]

**Bikes.js**

```
import { BIKES, BikeTypes, BikeSize } from '../../data'
const Bikes = () => {
    return <div className="bikes-page">
        <div>
            <hr className="bike-bottom-line" />
            <BikesList items={BIKES} />
        </div>
        <div className="bikes-map">
            <MapContainer style={{ height: '50rem' }} coords={BIKES} mapZoom={9} />
        </div>
    </div>
}

export default Bikes
```

**MapContainer.js** (Component made with react-leaflet)

```
const MapContainer = (props) => {
    const DEFAULT_LATITUDE = 40.500;
    const DEFUALT_LANGITUDE = 49.500;
    return (
        <Map style={props.mapStyle} center={[DEFAULT_LATITUDE, DEFUALT_LANGITUDE]} zoom={props.mapZoom || 7} >
            <TileLayer
                url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            />
            {
                props.coords ?
                    props.coords.map(mark => {
                        return <Marker
                            position={[mark.location.lat, mark.location.lng]}
                            icon={biker}
                            key={mark.id} >
                            <Popup className="popup">
                                <Link to={`/b/${mark.id}`} className="popup-container">
                                    <img src={mark.images[0]} alt={mark.title} />
                                    <div className="popup-container__title">
                                        <h3> {mark.title} </h3>
                                        {mark.size}" · {mark.price.first}azn/s
                                    </div>
                                </Link>
                            </Popup>
                        </Marker>
                    }) : null
            }

        </Map >
    )
}

export default MapContainer
```

**BikesList.js**  (left side - List)

```
const BikesList = (props) => {
    if (props.items.length === 0) {
        return <h2>Elan tapılmadı</h2>
    }

    return (
        <ul className="bikes-list">
            {props.items.map((bike) => (
                <BikeItem
                    key={bike.id}
                    id={bike.id}
                    image={bike.images[0]}
                    title={bike.title}
                    city={bike.city}
                    size={bike.size}
                    price={bike.price.first}
                    creator={bike.creator}
                    maxLength={24}
                />
            ))}
        </ul>
    )
}

export default BikesList
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution myself. It was easy :) Here it is:

**First** ,  in the Bikes.js file, I made an *isHovered* state and gives it null as a default. Then made handleHoverMarker(id) function with *id* which will get it from specific hovered item's id. In function I changed setIsHovered's value to this sent id. So then I shared ***isHovered*** and ***handleHoverMarker*** with props.

**Bikes.js**

```
const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(null)
const handleHoverMarker = (id) => {
        setIsHovered(id)
}
<div>
   <BikesList handleHoverMarker={handleHoverMarker} items={filteredDataState} />
</div>
<div className="bikes-map">
   <MapContainer isHovered={isHovered} style={{ height: '50rem' }} coords={BIKES} mapZoom={9} />
</div>
```

**Second**, *handleHoverMarker* props sent to the BikeItem component which represents each of items in list.

**BikesList.js**

```
<ul className="bikes-list">
            {props.items.map((bike) => (
                <BikeItem
                    key={bike.id}
                    id={bike.id}
                    image={bike.images[0]}
                    title={bike.title}
                    city={bike.city}
                    size={bike.size}
                    price={bike.price.first}
                    creator={bike.creator}
                    maxLength={24}
                    handleHoverMarker={props.handleHoverMarker}
                />
            ))}
</ul>
```

In the **BikeItem.js** set mouseHover events and pass the id with **handleHoverMarker(id)** function. So we will know which item hovered with id.

*Note: I didn't write all codes in BikeItem.js only took the necessary part*

**BikeItem.js**

```
<li onMouseEnter={()=> props.handleHoverMarker(props.id):null} onMouseLeave={()=>props.handleHoverMarker(null):null} key={props.id}>
```

So here we come back to the MapContainer which will show hovered item's location

**MapContainer.js**

```
{props.coords ?
   props.coords.map(mark => {
                return <Marker
                position={[mark.location.lat, mark.location.lng]}
                icon={biker}
                opacity={props.isHovered === mark.id ? .7 :1}
                key={mark.id} >
                   <Popup className="popup">
                     <Link to={`/b/${mark.id}`} className="popup container">
                       <div className="popup-container__title">
                          <h3> {mark.title}</h3>
                       </div>
                     </Link>
                </Popup>
               </Marker>
 }) : null}
```

Here I changed **opacity** value conditionally with ***props.isHovered*** which we sent from Bikes.js file.

Note: I couldn't changed marker's style because I didn't found a way from documentaton of leaflet map. So logic is the same, you can do it with Google Maps too. Enjoy good luck :)